# Immutable Vector or List Builder in Scala

Tags: scala, guava, immutability, scala-collections

I am running into situation where I need to extract certain entries into corresponding lists based on some condition. Here is my code

```
var keys = Vector[String]()
var data = Vector[String]()

for ((k, v) <- myMap) {
  if (v.endsWith("abc")) { keys = keys :+ v }
  if (v.endsWith("xyz")) { data = data :+ v }
}
```

What would be the best way to implement this logic without making *keys* and *data* as var? Is there such a thing as Immutable List builder in Scala?

For example, ImmutableList.Builder in guava (Java) https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.Builder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Scala collection comes with append-only builder:

```
val keysB, dataB = Vector.newBuilder[String]

for ((k, v) <- myMap) {
  if (v.endsWith("abc")) { keysB += v }
  if (v.endsWith("xyz")) { dataB += v }
}

val keys = keysB.result()
val data = dataB.result()
```

Comment: That's exactly I was looking for... not sure why it didn't come up in Google search. Thank you!

Comment: @Programmer this is fairly uncommon usage. I personally only needed it once when I was making extensions methods for stdlib collections. Very often you can get away with map/filter/collect/etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could just partition the values as needed.

```
val (keys, notKeys) = myMap.values.partition(_.endsWith("abc"))
val (data, _)       = notKeys.partition(_.endsWith("xyz"))
```

Your `keys` and `data` collections will be `List[String]` instead of `Vector` but that's an easy mod if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What about using foldLeft?

```
val map: Map[Int, String] = Map(
    1 -> "abc",
    2 -> "xyz",
    3 -> "abcxyz",
    4 -> "xyzabc"
)

val r = map.foldLeft((Seq.empty[String], Seq.empty[String])) {
    case ((keys, data), (k, v)) =>
        if (v.endsWith("abc")) {
            (keys :+ v, data)
        }
        else if (v.endsWith("xyz")) {
            (keys, data :+ v)
        }
        else {
            (keys, data)
        }

}
r match { 
    case (keys, data) =>
        println(s"keys: $keys")
        println(s"data: $data")
}
```

Comment: This quickly becomes ugly when a) there are more ifs and b) value needs to be added to more than one collection

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov, am I solving all problems in the world using this exact piece of code? The author asked exact question, I answered solution which solves it.

Answer (score -1):

If you're forced to use a `var` or mutable collection (beyond your needs for optimization), you're probably not thinking about the problem correctly.

Suppose we had a map `m`:

```
Map(1 -> "abc", 2 -> "xyz")
```

Now, we can use recursion to solve this problem (and I've done it in a tail recursive form here):

```
  type Keys = Vector[String]
  type Data = Vector[String]
  def keyData(m: Map[Int, String]): (Keys, Data) = {
    def go(keys: Keys, data: Data, m: List[(Int, String)]): (Keys, Data) =
      m match {
        case (k, v) :: ks if v endsWith("abc") =>
          go(v +: keys, data, ks)
        case (k, v) :: ks if v endsWith("xyz") =>
          go(keys, v +: data, ks)
        case k :: ks =>
          go(keys, data, ks)
        case _ => (keys, data)
      }
    go(Vector.empty[String], Vector.empty[String], m.toList)
  }
```

This will take a map and produce a pair of vectors holding the string data that matches the predicates you listed. Now, suppose we wanted to abstract and partition our map elements into vectors satisfying any two predicates `p: Int => Boolean` or `q: Int => Boolean`. Then, we'd have something that looks like this:

```
  type Keys = Vector[String]
  type Data = Vector[String]
  def keyData(m: Map[Int, String], p: Int => Boolean, q: Int => Boolean): (Keys, Data) = {
    def go(keys: Keys, data: Data, m: List[(Int, String)]): (Keys, Data) =
      m match {
        case (k, v) :: ks if p(v) =>
          go(v +: keys, data, ks)
        case (k, v) :: ks if q(v) =>
          go(keys, v +: data, ks)
        case k :: ks =>
          go(keys, data, ks)
        case _ => (keys, data)
      }
    go(Vector.empty[String], Vector.empty[String], m.toList)
  }
```

Now, we can abstract this for any key and value types `K` and `V`:

```
def partitionMapBy[K, V](m: Map[K, V], p: V => Boolean, q: V => Boolean): (Vector[V], Vector[V]) = {
    def go(keys: Vector[V], data: Vector[V], m: List[(K, V)]): (Vector[V], Vector[V]) =
      m match {
        case (k, v) :: ks if p(v) =>
          go(v +: keys, data, ks)
        case (k, v) :: ks if q(v) =>
          go(keys, v +: data, ks)
        case k :: ks =>
          go(keys, data, ks)
        case _ => (keys, data)
      }
    go(Vector.empty[V], Vector.empty[V], m.toList)
  }
```

You'll notice that there's nothing fancy going on with the recursion here. This means we can use a fold to accomplish the same thing. Here's an implementation using `foldLeft`:

```
def partitionMapBy[K, V](m: Map[K, V])(p: V => Boolean)(q: V => Boolean): (Vector[V], Vector[V]) =
    m.foldLeft[(Vector[V], Vector[V])]((Vector.empty[V], Vector.empty[V])) {
      case (acc @ (keys: Vector[V], data: Vector[V]), (_, v: V)) =>
        if(p(v)) (v +: keys, data)
        else if(q(v)) (keys, v +: data)
        else acc
    }
```

And you can see, for `m`, [we get the this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcEvS.png) where, if you let `p` be `_ endsWith("abc")` and `q` be `_ endsWith("xyz")`, then you'll have exactly what you want.
`